# Eclipse JDT - How to watch non-public variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-jdt

I am not new to *programming* but I am just learning the **Java** language and **Eclipse**. I want to see how Java works internally for some of the various "standard" imported classes using Eclipse's debug facilities (JDT Debug). My setup (Oxygen w/ JDK SE8 on Windows 8.1) works fine as far as single stepping through the code but many of the imported Class variables are unable to be placed into a watchlist or expression monitor, which I think is because they are not defined as "public".

As an example: I want to learn how **java.math.BigInteger** works so I wrote a quick program which uses the **pow()** method. The program runs successfully, and when using debug mode I am able to track the flow fine as well. What I cannot seem to do is to see the values of the internal "default" (no access modifier) variables. Below are three such variables found in BigInteger.java (lines 2225-2231):

```
int powersOfTwo = partToSquare.getLowestSetBit();
long bitsToShift = (long)powersOfTwo * exponent;
if (bitsToShift > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    reportOverflow();
}

int remainingBits;
```

Any suggestions on how to expose these variables to JDT Debug for learning purposes?

Comment: Are you compiling your project against and launching it with a JDK?

Comment: @nitind - Yes, I think I stated that when I described my setup (JDK SE8) above. Originally I had not been using a JDK and when i would try and single step into a println() the debugger would complain and stop stepping. So I switched to the JDK and installed the src.zip file per a number of stackexchange posts. Everything seems to work fine except for this issue.

Comment: Did you make sure to change your launch configuration to use the JDK?

Comment: @nitind - I realize you are trying to help but this is the second time I have had to ask if you were not clear on what I wrote in the original question: What part of "_My setup (Oxygen **w/ JDK SE8** on Windows 8.1) **works fine** as far as single stepping through the code_" did you not understand? If I did not have the JDK configured correctly then single stepping would crash on the first Java internal method and I would not be able to see the names of the variables I am asking about. Sorry if I sound harsh but sometimes it is frustrating to be asked what I have already answered.

Comment: You'd be able to step through your own code even when launching with a JRE, and you wouldn't be seeing arg0 parameters with a JDK. But Stephan's right that local variables are not compiled and treated the same as fields and that they can still be removed or just inlined in the final class file. What you're asking for may simply not be possible for classes you are not compiling yourself.

Comment: Without the JDK and the `src.zip` file which comes with it the moment you singlestep (in your own code) into an *internal* Java method such as `Sprintln()` the debugger throws an error and will not continue. Additionally the sourcecode for **println()** or the **BigInteger** class are not visible under a JRE so I would not know the names of the variables I cannot watch if that was the case. Lastly, I was in error when I said the `arg(0)` represented the `pow()` parameters, the **arg(0)** I have been seeing turns out to be the one referenced in `main(String[] args)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not about public vs. non-public but about fields vs. local variables.

Compilation may drop information about local variables, so the debugger no longer has information about their names. In that case a watch expression using that name cannot be resolved. The [Variables view](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/variables/ref-variables_view.htm?cp=1_4_7_6) should, however, still show the value, albeit with artificial names like `arg0` ... You can still correlate the variable to what you see in the source code, as local variables are only added to the Variables view when during stepping you reach the corresponding declaration.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying @Stephan but I am not sure where I would look for these `arg0` style variable in Eclipse. Can you edit your answer to explain please?

Comment: I added a link as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sorry to say that this is not the case. The variables I mention are not showing in that window either. An `arg0` (and the `this` variable) does appear but it represents the parameters of the call to `pow()`, as well as a few variables marked `public` in the source code but everything marked `private` or with no access modifer (defaults) is just not showing up.

Comment: At a closer look BigInteger.class has **no** information about local variables at all. Which means: you are out of look, unless you run with a custom variant of rt.jar which was compiled with a proper variant of `-g`.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I would have thought that the core JDK files would all be very accessible in this way but I guess not. One wonders why Oracle makes this all so hard to access. Their current standard JDK installer deletes the src.zip file (or fails to copy it from the temp folder) for some bizarre reason, so you have to "grab" it mid-install after the automated unpack and before the temp files are cleared. Makes no sense to me but I am new to the Java community and I guess there are some Java platform "politics" to learn along with the code. Sigh.